# Como cambio de BASE DE DATOS DE SQLyog A SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server

```
private static $db_host = 'localhost';
private static $db_user = 'root';
private static $db_pass = '';
protected $db_name = 'db1_tercero';
```

Quiero saber que deberia de modificar
El problema es el siguiente Ese pedaso de codigo es de Mi Mysqlyog Ahora quiero cambiarlo a SQL SERVER pero no se como se hace eso.

Comment: Podrias ver [ask]. La pregunta es poco clara en que es lo que queres hacer y cual es tu problema.

Comment: Deberias cambiar los datos que correspondan al nuevo servidor. y el driver de conexion de ser necesario. A eso te referis?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que quiero hacer es cambiar de base de datos osea ya no usar Misqlyog sinos Sqlserver.

Comment: Misqlyog no es una base de datos. Es una ide para ver una base de datos mysql. Vos queres ir de una base de datos mysql a sqlserver. Por lo que digo que tu pregunta no es clara, es porque ademas de modificar todos esos parametros de conexion a la nueva base (que solo los sabes vos) tendras que cambiar los drivers de conexion.

Comment: @gianchi eXactamentes